# I/O error on GET request

Tags: java, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using gradle for api and got this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/SpringBootRestApi/api/user/":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
    at com.websystique.springboot.SpringBootRestTestClient.listAllUsers(SpringBootRestTestClient.java:21)
    at com.websystique.springboot.SpringBootRestTestClient.main(SpringBootRestTestClient.java:74)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: looks like what ever address specified in the URL went to a device or server that refused the connection. this would normally be due to several possible issues: (1) there is no server at the address, (2) a firewall prevented the request from reaching the server process, (3) there is a server but due to its settings the server refused the request, (4) there is a server and it is set up to accept the request however the address is incorrect such as wrong port number specified.

Comment: without additional information such as a description of the target server along with a sample of the source code, difficult to see the problem is.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing a similar problem connecting to a spring web service. It on was on localhost:8080, when I changed localhost to an actual IP address it worked.